# Using http.request in Node.JS while passing an API key

Tags: node.js, server-side

I am currently fiddling around with Node.JS to try to create a package for PostageApp to be able to send emails through our API.

To start, I am using the following code to test out how Node.JS can best interface with our API, but it doesn't seem to want to pass along the API key that I have attached as part of the headers.

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response) {
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started.");

var options = {
    host: 'api.postageapp.com',
    path: '/v.1.0/get_account_info.json',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { "api_key" : "MY API KEY HERE" }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});

req.end();
console.log("Request sent!");
```

I pulled this together using various examples and what not - it's not pretty, I know. However, using HTTPS, I finally got it to hit our API and get a response:

```
{"response":{"status":"unauthorized","message":"Invalid or inactive API key used","uid":null}}
```

The only conclusion I can come up with is that the API key is not getting passed along, and I would appreciate any help as to how to make that happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of code I have used to call web APIs with a key in the header:

```
  var api = http.createClient(80, 'api.example.org');

  var request = api.request('GET', '/api/foo', 
    {
      'host': 'api.example.org',
      'accept': 'application/json', 
      'api-key': 'apikeygoeshere' 
    });

  request.on('response', function (response) {});    
  request.end();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns a 405 error that causes the app to hang. :(

Comment: Did you use a GET or a POST? You can change my example to use a POST. It is not clear to me which app is hanging? Can you clarify.

Comment: Whoops. I changed it to POST but I don't think it's passing the API key through still, it isn't getting the correct response back.

Comment: Yep, works just fine. However, here's how I use the curl:
curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' { "api_key":"API KEY HERE" } ' https://api.postageapp.com/v.1.0/get_account_info.json

Comment: And I think the "-d" or data part of the cURL is what I am missing from my node.js script...

Comment: Yes, the key is not part of the HTTP request header. Instead it is part of the request body. You can pass your JSON string containing the key as a parameter to request.end("{'api_key':'KEY'");. Be sure to set the content-type header to application/json.

Comment: Yesss, there we go. Thank you so much Derrish!